# Как настроить Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Всем привет! Недавно начал учить js и скачал VS Code( до того работал только в Visual Studio). Потом установил все необходимое, по гайдам, и написал простенький код для начала

```js
    console.log(“Hello World”);
```

Когда запускаю код, через ctrl + alt + N мне вьіводится ошибка: Node.js не является используемой командой, что то вроде того, видел похожий вопрос, у меня потому что нет руського якзьіка просто вьіводится Node и куча символов (если что у меня нет папки Node.js и я не знаю как не создать)Как запустить код? Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: ` Потом установил все необходимое, по гайдам...` видимо не все по гайдам, раз пути к ноде не прописаны нормально.

Comment: переустановите node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm init
```

Запустите в консоли из директории с проектом

Comment: запустил, пишет ошибку: npm : Имя "npm" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы.